# Check if a BOOL is set (can't be done with ==nil)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, null

how do i check if a BOOL is set in objective-c (iphone)?

i know that it can be done with an int or float this way:
NSNumber *Num = [prefs floatForKey:@"key"];
for example

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can't.  A `BOOL` is either `YES` or `NO`.  There is no other state.  The way around this would be to use an `NSNumber` (`[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];`), and then check to see if the `NSNumber` itself is `nil`.  Or have a second `BOOL` to indicate if you've altered the value of the first.

Comment: Actually, a `BOOL` may not be `YES` or `NO`. The only safe way to work with `BOOL` is to check wither it is either `NO` or `!NO`. `BOOL` is a  `typedef` for `signed char`.

Comment: @dreamlax True, you could set a BOOL to 1 or 2, but to me that seems like a perversion of the purpose of the typedef.

Comment: @Dave, it isn't just about assingments, for example if a `BOOL` is the return value of a method that simply returns a value based on a `char`-sized bitmask operation then the return value may not be 0 or 1. Ideally the method should return `((flags & mask) == mask)` but it isn't required to do so.

Answer (score 5):

Annoyingly, Objective-C has no Boolean class. It certainly feels like it should and that trips a lot of people up. In collections and core data, all bools are stored as NSNumber instances.

It's really annoying having to convert back and forth all the time.

Comment: What would you gain having a Boolean class that you don't have with NSNumber?  You'd still have to convert back and forth with scalar BOOLs for storage in things like NSArray and Core Data.

Comment: @BradLarson A common mistake with using NSNumber as bool is a conditional formatted like the following `if (myNumber) {` where it is expected that @0 would be false and @1 would be true, but rather both are true as they are not nil. Ideally a bool primitive could exist that is false for both 0 or nil and true for 1, and checking the `!!` of it would allow for a nullability check. This is beneficial over NSNumber, because this primitive would still work in traditional conditional statements, primitive style, instead of having to call `.boolValue` on the object.

Answer (score 3):

By default, a bool value is set to 0 in Objective-C, so you don't need to check if your bool value is nil anytime.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this instead...

```
@import Foundation;

@interface CSBool : NSObject

+ (CSBool *)construct:(BOOL)value;

@property BOOL value;

@end

#import "CSBool.h"

@implementation CSBool

+ (CSBool *)construct:(BOOL)value {
    CSBool *this = [self new];
    this.value = value;
    return this;
}
@end
```